# which is more popular brake, disc brake or drum brakes in passenger cars in US? can anybody give a rough idea about percentage

Tags: brakes, braking

i am unable to find that which is most common brakes used as braking system in USA, as i am studying the braking system of vehicles in USA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about maintenance. It's the sort of thing someone may study to get a historical vs modern view (as older cars had drum brakes and newer ones tend to have disc brakes) but it would require a lot of assumptions (eg is this cars registered as road legal, farm vehicles etc) - so I just think it's too broad for here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Agree with you.